# special update mysql like .= php operator

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Is there a way in MYSQL to UPDATE a column in a table adding some new text at the end of the current one?

For example I have in my table a field named "names".
I just want to add some new names at the end of this field.

So before the update the names field is :"name1,name2,"

and I'm adding the new text: "name3,name4".

Is there a way to directly UPDATE this table without extracting data for saving the field names with "name1,name2,name3,name4,"?

In php I would directly do it with the .= operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CONCAT() function like this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = CONCAT(column, 'new-value');
```

Of course you can also prepend (and even append):

```
UPDATE table SET column = CONCAT('prepend this', column, 'new-value');
```

Or join multiple columns to one.